# Catalog search goes blank showing nothing

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

There was an Error in a search page. It was showing blank no scripting, while searching anything.

> 2015-06-25T07:10:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   require_once(/home/patelman/public_html/..app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /home/patelman/public_html/../app/code/local/themename/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php
>   on line 5

I got this error in system log file.

Comment: Please make sure Magento logging is on and check the system and error log for exceptions. Also check the apache error logs for PHP errors or turning error displaying on

Comment: It's not showing any error.

Comment: Dit you add a 3rd party plugin or change code or a layout file? Without any information we cant help you

Comment: I used poli pay extension only and I haven't made any changes in code and layout file.

Comment: Hi Sander, Can you help me with how to put Question on this forum as you put it on hold. Really I need help.

Comment: We need an error or something else to help you debug. A white page can be just about anything from an issue in the htaccess to a php error

Comment: Please post your solution as comment here. It might be useful for future visitors

Comment: Got Solution for this:
There was a problem in the below path.

require_once('app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php');

this path was wrong in "Ajaxcatalog/controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php" File.


It may occur because of using some third party extension. I am not sure.

Comment: If you have solved it, please go ahead and answer your own question then mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that is a problem with Ajaxcatalog module you installed. It could not find Result controller. You may try following ways: 
- If you enable compilation, you should re-compile it to solve the problem. 
- Check & Make sure the module include correct file path. 
- Contact module author
- Disable the module :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to ResultController of catalogsearch module is not included properly.

Open  ***app/code/local/themename/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php*** file and add below code on top.

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers',Mage_CatalogSearch').DS.'ResultController.php';
```